# Minecraft crashed with this report?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I have just bought minecraft for using the latest Minecraft launcher and Minecraft 1.8. However, when I launch Minecraft. I get the following error:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Surprise! Haha. Well, this is awkward.

Time: 30/12/13 12:36
Description: Initializing game

org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:252)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at azi.ad(SourceFile:325)
    at azi.f(SourceFile:696)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:152)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:252)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at azi.ad(SourceFile:325)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at azi.f(SourceFile:696)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:152)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.7.4
    Operating System: Windows 8 (x86) version 6.2
    Java Version: 1.7.0_45, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (mixed mode, sharing), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 5196192 bytes (4 MB) / 26808320 bytes (25 MB) up to 518979584 bytes (494 MB)
    JVM Flags: 2 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx512M
    AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    Launched Version: 1.7.4
    LWJGL: 2.9.1
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
    GL Caps: 
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: []
    Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    Vec3 Pool Size: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Anisotropic Filtering: Off (1)
```

I have seen a solution which is to update my graphics drivers which I already did.
Instead of using the .exe, use a jar, also done.
So I'm new to PC gaming and do not know certain things. Why is there no pre-requirement checker with the installation? Is there one somewhere?

Comment: Could you clarify the probable solution?

Comment: I don't see how this is even remotely a duplicate of that other question. That said, it's very unclear to me what exactly you're asking.